# How to start with OpenRTB?

Tags: ads

if I am new a new publisher want to implement a openrtb system for getting ads from the DSP etc. how should i go about implementing it. Like what languages can I use or how to proceed.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to contact an [SSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supply-side_platform) that has already everything implemented and connected to live DSPs.

> Supply-side platform or sell-side platform (SSP) is a technology
>   platform to enable web publishers to manage their advertising space
>   inventory, fill it with ads, and receive revenue.

Also consider using [header bidding](http://prebid.org/overview/intro.html) to work with multiple SSPs simultaneously

> Header Bidding (also known as header auctions, parallel bidding, or
>   header bidding) is a technique that involves running SSP & Ad Exchange
>   code directly on page so publishers can receive bids on their
>   inventory that may be unavailable through their primary ad server and
>   exchange

Answer (score 0):

If you are a new publisher, the first thing that you have to decide is which SSP and exchange should be used. There are few open-source platforms such as OpenSSP and OpenX. If you want a package of all in one, my recommendation is to go ahead with Google Ad Manager.